# Display Group Name Value of each group in a column header outside the group

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdlc, ssrs-2012, ssrs-grouping

I have an SSRS 2012 table report with groups; each group is broken i.e.  one group for one page, and  there are multiple groups in multiple pages.

'GroupName' column has multiple values - X,Y,Z,......

I need to group 'GroupName' with X,Y,Z,..... ie value X in page 1,value Y in page 2, value Z in page 3...

This is not an issue obviously!

Now, I need to display another column (ABC) in this table report (outside the group column  'GroupName');  this outside column itself is another column header (not a group header) in the table (report) and it derives its name partly from the 'GroupName' column:

Example:

> - Value X for GroupName  in page 1 will mean,  in page 1, column Name of ABC column must be ABC-X
> - Value Y for GroupName  in page 2 will mean, in page 2, column Name of ABC column must be ABC-Y
> - Value Z for GroupName  in page 3 will mean,  in page 3, column Name of ABC column must be ABC-Z
>
> ie the column name of ABC must be dynamic as per the GroupName  values
> (X,Y,Z....)
>
> ---
>
> Page1:
>
> GroupName             **Clm ABC-X**
> **X**
>
> Page2:
>
> GroupName             **Clm ABC-Y**
> **Y**
>
> Page3:
>
> GroupName             **Clm ABC-Z**
> **Z**

I have been able to use First(ReportItems!GroupName.Value) in the **Page Header** to get GroupNames displayed in each page;
I get X in page 1, Y in page 2, Z in page 3.....

However, when I use **ReportItems** (that refers to a group name) in the **Report Body** outside the group,

I get the following error:

**Report item expressions can only refer to other report items within the same grouping scope or a containing grouping scope**

I need to get the X, Y, Z ... in each page for the column ABC. Is there any suggestion you can provide me?

I have been able to use this - First(Fields!GroupName.Value);
however, I get ABC-X, ABC-X, ABC-X in each of the pages for the ABC column,
instead of ABC-X in page 1, ABC-Y in page 2, ABC-Z in page 3, ...

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your report designer to get a better visual idea of how you build everything? Like when you say "outside the group" what do you mean with group? What is the group represented by, a Rectangle?